# mytop ( a mysql monitoring tool) thread view dosen't consider queries commited by other users in Queries

Tags: mysql, monitoring

I ran a program which commits 2000 inserts into a table. but in mytop thread veiw the item "Queries" which keeps track of number of queries is increased just by 2 each time mytop view is refreshed and that is the number of queries mytop commits itself to get info from mysql. I don't know why the number of insert queries is not added... .

another matter is that my command view has just a few items

```
   show status 

show variables 

show processlist

    set option

   Compression
```

but it is told to have more, such as number of select queries (http://www.opensourcetutorials.com/tutorials/Server-Side-Coding/Administration/mytop/page4.html). again I don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mytop. But for a monitoring to get its stats, it has to query the server itself. By looking at the screenshots it look mytop uses "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" and "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS" to get its stats.

I use [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php#monyog), which also does same kind of querying to the server like  "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST", "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS", "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES", "SHOW SLAVE STATUS" to show its statistics.

I think it will answer for your 2 extra query that increment every mytop refresh.